# System crashes after January 10, 2018 updates

Tags: 16.04, updates, crash

I faithfully install all of Canonical's system updates.  After installing today's, and rebooting my system to complete installation, the system hung and was unable to complete the update.  While I had no problem recovering by using earlier builds, every attempt to install the latest updates produced the same result.  System diagnostics failed to show any hardware problems or material defects in earlier versions of the OS.  What could be happening?

Comment: It is likely a bug see - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1742323 . For now you should be able to boot an old kernel and try again when a new kernel is released.